# Detect URL in HTACCESS and respond?

Tags: .htaccess

Essentially if I'm testing locally, I do not want to forward to www.

What I would like essentially in .htaccess is :

```
<if local.trunk is not present in url>
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www\.
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(.+)$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</if>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !.*local.*
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unsure.

If its local, the URL doesn't need WWW, otherwise if WWW isn't present, then forward to www.

current code:

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: You don't want to redirect to `www.localhost`? You could add `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` !=localhost` prior to your RewriteConds.

Comment: to exclude something, you have to add another RewriteCond. I edited my answer.